# HTML unit displaying wrong characters

Tags: htmlunit

I'm using HTMLUnit. I am accessing the pages however special (Maltese) characters are being displayed wrongly. For example, ġuvni is displayed as ?uvni

```
HtmlPage page = submit_button.click();
System.out.println(page.asText());
```

I suspect it's an encoding problem, though I don't find any `page.setPageEndoding` or some similar method... Has anyone had such a problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your page is in UTF-8 by putting this meta tag in your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Hmm when I get the encoding of the page it does come up as "utf-8".

Comment: Actually what happened was that the console output for Eclipse wasn't set as "UTF-8". Once I changed it, the characters got displayed fine. Console-encoding could be changed as shown here: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/ 10x!